# Without SAT or ACT, how will college admission function?

Tags: united-states, undergraduate

During the pandemic, many universities in the United States have suspended the requirement of SAT, ACT, or equivalent tests. I work in one of them. It seems that some universities have removed such requirements permanently. My personal experience is that the removal of the test scores has very noticeable effects.

I wonder if there are measurable effects across the country. Moreover, what is replacing test scores? Obviously Caltech cannot accept 100% applicants, so what is the filtering mechanism now?

Comment: Do you work in admissions?

Comment: No, I'm a faculty member, hence the question.

Comment: "Obviously CalTech cannot accept 100% of applicants". This statement is strange to me, because standardized test scores have never been the only (or even the primary) method by which applicants are filtered. GPA, writing samples, essays, extra-curriculars, community involvement...these are all filtering mechanisms and many argue they are better indicators of future student success.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "noticeable effects"? Could they be attributable to the ongoing pandemic more generally?

Comment: *My personal experience is that the removal of the test scores has very noticeable effect.* --- It might be helpful to give more context for this assertion, since if "noticeable effect" is somewhat of a euphemism for "declining quality" (in background knowledge, in intrinsic ability/potential, in ability or desire to work hard, etc.), then the effect you're seeing might be almost entirely due to issues related to online-only learning due to COVID.

Comment: @psithurism, Good point, certainly there are many other filtering mechanisms, but I'll be surprised if test score is not a major factor. I could be wrong, but I really cannot imagine admission officers comparing writing samples from a student scored in the 10th percentile and that from a student scored in the 90th percentile. At least in my university, test scores are used to organize applicants into groups, other factors matter within the same groups.

Comment: @Bilbo my understanding is that in lieu of test scores admissions committees are increasingly using GPA as the initial filtering mechanism, adjusted by multi-factor criteria / holistic review.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, Certainly, whatever difference in the student body we observe now will be strongly linked to the long pandemic.  That said, it's reasonable to isolate the variables: Many students on my campus took SAT/ACT, and we know their scores (at least we ended up knowing as they are still needed for other purpose).  It is easy to correlate ACT scores that are lower than our previous requirement with their worst 1st-year performance.

Comment: @Bilbo You, as a random faculty member, know your student's SAT/ACT scores from their application?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, Yes, for ACT.  For SAT, just a range.

Comment: Some context for down votes will be helpful. This is a nontrivial restructuring of how higher-ed works in a not insignificant percentage of universities in a not so small country.

Comment: @Bilbo likely related to the implied confirmation bias present in the question and on this thread.

Comment: Regarding knowing ACT scores, my student class lists from the mid 1990s (3 years at a certain nearly open admissions university) included the students' ACT math scores (virtually 100% took only the ACT), but I don't think I saw either ACT or SAT scores of (all my) students anywhere else I've taught (1983 to 2005). So knowing the scores is definitely possible, but likely not very common, and probably MUCH less common now than in the mid 1990s.

Comment: Just a heads up that your question may unfortunately be closed. We don't take questions on "undergraduate admissions" since these decisions are mostly made by the admissions office, and academics (e.g., professors) are only marginally aware of what goes on in admissions offices.

Comment: "Some context for down votes will be helpful" I didn't DV, but obviously you know that Caltech doesn't take the top students in SAT rank-order alone, so that part comes off a little dismissive. "This is a nontrivial restructuring of how higher-ed works" This is overstated. It might be a "restructuring" of applications, but of all of higher ed? nah

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, When I was in a larger R1 university, student scores are generally inaccessible. I am now in a regional university where higher percentage of faculty members are involved in advising, placement tests, and scholarship committees. Seeing ACT records indirectly is not uncommon.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, Sure, it's probably not going to affect CalTech.  But the downstream effect may require smaller universities to have nontrivial restructuring.  My department is rearranging lower level math courses in response to changes in student population (though ACT requirement is not the only reason). As an advisor, I'm also seeing students who could have end up in "better" universities had scores been a major factor. In any case, I think there is some reasonable answers that would be relevant to this SE community. Oh well.

Comment: @Bilbo I think your question would be better received with a lot more of the context you've left in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the filtering hasn't changed much. In the US, admissions have always been broad based, not deterministic based on a few numbers. Lots of things can be considered, including GPA, the relevant courses passed, letters of recommendation, personal statements, etc.

Basing decisions on a single number is overly simplistic.

Moreover, the standardized tests are poor measures in any case, making it easier to drop them. They measure mostly the retention of facts, rather that the possession of skill and insight.